# Zipline-trader: Unknown syntax [{'sid': Equity(1576 [JPM])} -

Tags: python, dictionary

I am relatively new to Python and am working my way through the zipline-trader library. I came across a data structure that I am unfamiliar with and was wondering if you could help me access a certain element out of it.

I ran a backtest on zipline-trader and have the results-DataFrame that has a column "positions" which includes the portfolio positions for a given day.

Here is an example of the content of that column:

```
[{'sid': Equity(1576 [JPM]), 'amount': 39, 'cost_basis': 25.95397, 'last_sale_price': 25.94}, {'sid': Equity(2942 [UNH]), 'amount': 11, 'cost_basis': 86.62428999999999, 'last_sale_price': 86.58}]
```

The syntax I am unfamiliar with is the part "Equity (1576 [JPM])" - can anybody explain to me what this is? Also, can you please let me know how to access the "[JPM]"-part of it? Ultimately, what I am trying to do is access that cell of the DataFrame using a loc-function and producing the result "{JPM: 1576, UNH: 2942}"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is (likely to be) an object of type Equity. If the structure you showed us was stored in a variable `data` then the object can be fetched using

```
eq = data[0]['sid']
```

The text when it's printed will be coming from the `__str__` method defined in the Equity class, so it doesn't really tell us anything about how to access it. You would have to look up the documentation.

If you are able to access the object in an interactive session then you could run the `help` command against it and that might contain something useful. Again, if the structure you showed us was stored in a variable `data` then you could do:

```
help(data[0]['sid'])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful!